# Having 2 xcode windows side by side

Tags: xcode, screen-resolution

So I have a 1920x1080 display, and when I try to run two xcode windows side by side, they overlap each other. I originally faced this problem on my MBP 1650x1050 screen but I am expecting for screen real estate.

Anyone have any ideas how to get it run side by side without the xcode windows getting cropped? I'm using BetterTouchTool to snap the windows to the left and right.

Here's a picture of the cropping:

[image]

Comment: That's the lowest that the 2 windows can be resized, I can't fit 2 side by side

Comment: The horizontal resize is at it's minimum in the screenshot above. I can't make the window any smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible, OS X applications have predetermined minimum height and width attributes, which as far as I know can't be overridden. Believe me, I'm dealing with the same problem. It's pretty frustrating, but there isn't anything you can do about it.

Comment: I thought as much, Frustrating that I bought the 1920x1800 screen for more real estate only to find out that's it's capped. Thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 9):

Hide the toolbar (**View > Hide Toolbar**) and you will be able to resize Xcode windows to smaller sizes than when the toolbar is visible.

You may also want to hide the Navigator (**View > Navigators > Hide Navigator**) to make more room for the editor view.

Here is a screenshot with a 1440x900 resolution:

[image: Screenshot at 1440x900 resolution]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the toolbar & navigator. NSPostWhenIdle's answer was correct for my case. I have since upgraded to the Retina MBP, so the 1920x1080 resolution solved my problem. Thanks